# Passar um array de objetos via AJAX por POST e ler as propriedades dos objetos no PHP

Tags: php, ajax, json, array, post

Estou tendo alguns problemas para resolver esta situação. Estou tentando passar meu array de objetos via AJAX para outra página em PHP e ler as propriedades que estão dentro de cada objeto dentro desse array. Pra vocês tentarem entender melhor vou postar o código aqui...

Meu JavaScript está montando o objeto e retornando estes dados (valores de exemplo):

```js
[{"horario":"14:00","id_bus_rota_parada":"1","id_bus_rota":"0","id_bus_parada":"22"},{"horario":"15:00","id_bus_rota_parada":"1","id_bus_rota":"0","id_bus_parada":"23"}];
```

Estes objetos estão dentro do array "dados[]"...

Então eu tento passar este array de objetos para o PHP já transformado em JSON.

```js
$.ajax({
        url: "../actions/rota_inserir.php",
        type: "post",
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify(dados),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.sucesso == true) {
                var n = noty({
                    text: "Rota cadastrada com sucesso!",
                    type: 'success'
                });
            }
        },
    });
```

Agora eu não sei como receber estes dados no PHP, eu fiz uma linha de código mas não funcionou...

```html
$horarioParada = $_POST['horario'];
```

Comment: Ah, se eu tentar visualizar o objeto pelo navegador usando dados[0].id_bus_parada por exemplo, ele retorna o valor corretamente.

Comment: O atributo data do Ajax deve ser um objeto é não um string!

Comment: Ta, e como eu faria para ler as propriedades do objeto no PHP, ao invés de usar $horarioParada = $_POST['horario'];

Comment: Vejo que seu script está montando um array com 2 objetos e pretende inserir os dados destes objetos de forma massiva! É isto mesmo? No exemplo, são 2 objetos, podem ser mais ou será apenas 2 em todas as situações?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Atribua uma referência aos dados que se quer enviar `pedido`, e remova a definição do cabeçalho `contentType: 'application/json'`.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "../actions/rota_inserir.php",
    type: "post",
    data: {pedido: JSON.stringify(dados)},
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        if (data.sucesso == true) {
            var n = noty({
                text: "Rota cadastrada com sucesso!",
                type: 'success'
            });
        }
    },
});
```

No php, define a saída como `json`, e verifica se foi feita a requisição, e logo, converte os dados enviados através de `pedido` para uma array, e retorna um status em json:

```
header("Content-Type: application/json");
if(isset($_POST['pedido'])){
  $dados = json_decode($_POST['pedido'], true);
  print json_encode(['sucesso'=>true]);
}
```

No final, no client, podes receber ou não o retorno como `json`, isso vai depender do que quiseres fazer realmente.

> Exemplos: [Ajax - _POST](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: Era exatamente isso que eu queria, estava faltando o json_decode pra mim, agora consigo acessar os valores no PHP usando por exemplo $dados[0]["horario"], muito obrigado!

Comment: @MatheusCavallini Você pode variar na maneira como fazes isso, é só ir explorando o método `$.ajax`, e se quiser usar `object` em vez de `array` é só remover o `true` no final do `json_decode`.

Answer (score 1):

Você não precisa fazer essa conversão para json para enviar por post, seria basicamente passar o objeto com os dados

```
$.post('../actions/rota_inserir.php', {horario: '14:00'}, function (retorno) {
    // trata o retorno
});
```

Caso queira retornar um objeto do php, também dá, basicamente teria que fazer um json_encode no objeto e dar um echo

```
<?php 
$obj = new stdClass();
$obj->success = true;
echo json_encode($obj);
```

Ai nesse caso voce tem que converter de quando ele chegar la no post

```
$.post('../actions/rota_inserir.php', {horario: '14:00'}, function (retorno) {
  try {
    retorno = $.parseJSON(retorno);
    if(retorno.success) {
      alert("Rota cadastrada com sucesso!");
    } 
  } catch (ex) {
    console.log(ex); 
  }
});
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda, sua resposta também está correta, mas o Edilson entendeu o que eu realmente queria, mas lhe agradeço mesmo assim!